# Graph theory cycle problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, eulerian-path

Question background: In each of the pictures below; there are line segments connecting black dots (7 line segments in the left picture and 12 line segments in the right picture).

[image: TwoGraphsTwoPotentialEulerCycles]

Question asks to find out of "it's possible to draw a closed (cycle) continuous line that crosses each of these line segments exactly once; whilst staying inside the dashed rectangle".

**My understanding of this question...**

My understanding is that it's asking to treat each "region" as a vertex & then try to go through / over each existing line segment (once) until I return to the same region / vertex (if possible).

Comment: See, the graph in this case lies not within the black dots and lines, but rather in the space between them

Comment: If that comment seems too cryptic: I think what is being asked is wheter you can draw a line that **crosses** each of the segments (a segment here consists of two black dots at each end and a continuous line between them) exactly once and loops around. So in essence the vertices are the white polygons and the edges are the boundaries between them

Comment: You're not using any of the lines, you are drawing a new line and expected to cross each of the existing lines. Converting this into a more natural "path" is the crux of the solution.

Comment: Not using any of dashed lines, yes? Biggest problem is actually translating the presentation of these graphs.

Comment: Wait, it's not asking to trace over the existing edges; it's asking to use a region as a starting vertex & move over each existing line segment to see if I can return to the same region / vertex after crossing over each black line segment, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

After you construct the graph by treating each region as a vertex and construct an edge between them for each line they share as boundary, the question is asking if there is an eulerian cycle.

An undirected graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has even degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component.

Comment: Correct. I finished this a few hours ago. The graph on the left doesn't have an Euler cycle (two vertices with odd degree of 3) & the graph on the right does have an Euler cycle.